# Custom layout within a Gallery question, Android!

Tags: android, gallery, adapter

Here is what I want.  I want to have a gallery of custom views of layouts.  However I want to be able to set setText on textViews within each layout element of the gallery.  I am displaying the blank layouts successfully in a gallery view.

However, when I try to setText on a resource from the layout I get a NullPointer exception on the setText function.  It says it cannot find my textView..  Here is my code for  the getView in my custom Adapter for my gallery.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.adapter_layout, null);
     convertView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
     TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

      //NULL POINTER HERE !!!!
      text1.setText("YOYOYOYOYOYO");
}
```

Comment: NeverMind all i had to do was add convertView.findViewById(...);    DUMB MISTAKE!! wasted like 2 hours..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `findViewById()` on the activity, not the view returned by the inflator. Try

```
     TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
```